# arranging array elements in a group

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array with numbers. They are to be split in MxN (rows x cols), as shown in the figure.
After MXN values are encountered I need to add the group positions in the new array.

Group numbers are shown at bottom.

How do I arrange as required using javascript?

[image]

Comment: How does `m` and `n` affect the output?

Comment: From the picture, it seems that you are looking for an output like this `[[1,3,7,2,5,9],[4,32]]`. Can you verify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
var m = 3
var n = 2
var required = a.map( (val, idx) => [val, Math.floor(idx/(m*n))])
```

Perhaps you wanted this

- Iterate through array
- Return array of array with second index updating every mxn

Comment: You beat me my 10 secs. Was about to post and saw a new answer notification. Just a pointer though, add explanation

Answer (score 2):

You could just map the values with a result of the division by the `m` and `n` values.

```js
var data = [1, 3, 7, 2, 5, 9, 4, 32],
    m = 3,
    n = 2,
    result = data.map(function (a, i) {
        return [a, Math.floor(i / (m * n))];
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `array#reduce`.

```js
var array = [1,3,7,2,5,9,4,32], 
    m = 3,
    n = 2;
    
var result = array.reduce((res, v, i) => {
  res.push([v,Math.floor(i/(m*n))]);
  return res
} , []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the image it looks as if you are looking to segregate the items `[1,3,7,2,5,9,4,32]` into nested arrays as `[[1,3,7,2,5,9],[4,32]]`

In this case, try this (*comments inline*)

```js
var output=[[]], m = 3, n = 2; //initialize the output
[1,3,7,2,5,9,4,32].forEach( function(item, index){ //iterate the array
   if ( ( index % (m*n) == 0) && index > 0)
   {
      output.push([]); // if index value reaches the multiple of m*n, add new []
   }
   output[ output.length - 1 ].push( item );
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(output))
```